# CausalImpact package in R doesn't work for Poisson bsts model

Tags: r, bayesian, causality

I'd like to use the CausalImpact package in R to estimate the impact of an intervention on infectious disease case counts. We typically characterize the distributions of case counts as either Poisson or negative binomial. The `bsts()` function allows us to specify the Poisson family. However this encountered an error in `CausalImpact()`

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
y <- rpois(100, 1.2 * x1)
y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 10
data <- cbind(y, x1)
pre.period <- c(1, 70)
post.period <- c(71, 100)
post.period.response <- y[post.period[1] : post.period[2]]
y[post.period[1] : post.period[2]] <- NA
ss <- AddLocalLevel(list(), y)
bsts.model <- bsts(y ~ x1, ss, family="poisson", niter = 1000)
impact <- CausalImpact(bsts.model = bsts.model,
                   post.period.response = post.period.response)

Error in rnorm(prod(dim(state.samples)), 0, sigma.obs) : invalid arguments
```

This is due to the fact that `bsts.model` has no `sigma.obs` slot when generated using `family="poisson"`.

Am I doing this correctly or is there another way to use CausalImpact with Poisson data? (I'd also love to be able to use negative binomial data, but I won't get too greedy).

Last, is this the best place for coding issues for CausalImpact? I didn't see an Issues tab on the GitHub page.

Comment: There was a causalimpact Google Group but they closed last year and requested people post here. So I think you're in the right place.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMiles though I am concerned that there is a causalimpact tag in stats.stackexchange, but not here.

Comment: You could create a tag. Also, if you mention @kay-brodersen does it ping them? (I'm not sure.)

Comment: @salauer Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @tom No, I didn't. I've moved on to using different methods of causal inference, such as targeted maximum likelihood estimation (TMLE).